# How to send request header in upper case?

Tags: jquery, ajax, http, header, http-headers

I'm trying to add a header using Jquery AJAX in the request which is in uppercase. I found that header is getting converted to lower case automatically. I'm using chrome browser and inspected the header from chrome's network tab.

"X-AUTH-TOKEN" : "value" is getting converted to "x-auth-token" : "value"

Is there any way to retain the header's key in the same format ?

Comment: It doesn't matter either way - HTTP headers are not case sensitive. See section 4.2 of the spec: https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec4.html#sec4.2 Is there a specific reason you want to do this?

Comment: @Rory McCrossan Yeh, that's true. But I don't have access to the server side Code. It accepts the above header in the upper case.

Comment: I have a similar problem, just the other way around (gets converted to uppercase). did you ever find a solution?